# Alternate approach to get the desired output "Numpy Vectorized "

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an alternate method to get the desired output? Right now it's working fine by importing numpy package by calling the `numpy.vectorize` function.

I do not want to import the package, I would like to implement this by writing raw python code. Any suggestions??

```
def comp(a, b):
    if a < b:
        return a+b
    else:
        return a-b

import numpy as np
b = np.vectorize(comp)
c = b([1, 2, 3], 2)
c
```

Supposed to get results like `[3, 0, 1]`

Comment: You shouldn't be using vectorize here anyways.  This would be something like `np.where(a < b, a + b, a - b)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
[comp(x, 2) for x in [1,2,3]]
```

Or `map` the function over two lists:

```
list(map(comp, [1,2,3], [2,2,2]))
```

Or use `functools.partial` and map its result over the list:

```
import functools
list(map(functools.partial(comp, b=2), [1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, using `itertools` to create a cyclic iterator out of `[2]`:

```
import itertools


list(map(comp, [1, 2, 3], itertools.cycle([2])))
```

or, without using `itertools` but fundamentally the same idea (note that you could also use any `range(n)` for `n >= 3` and you will get the same result):

```
list(map(comp, [1, 2, 3], (2 for _ in range(3))))
```

---

## EDIT

You could also have your own decorator.
For example, if you are willing to always give *1D* iterables and to always cycle the shortest ones, you may use this (primitive but functional) code:

```
import itertools


def iterize(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        max_len = max(len(arg) for arg in args)
        return list(map(
             func,
             *(arg if len(arg) == max_len else itertools.cycle(arg)
               for arg in args),
             **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

which can be used like this:

```
@iterize
def comp(a, b):
    return a + (b if a < b else -b)


comp([1, 2, 3], [2])
# [3, 0, 1]

comp(range(10), range(5))
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Of course may envision different ways of dealing with the arguments, handling different lengths, etc.